# Need assistance with excel macro- vba

Tags: excel, vba

have a set of `SUMIF` formulas that I need to adjust frequently & the only thing I need to adjust is the 3rd part of it. The 3rd part, or sum range, columns need to be shifted over to the right by 1 column each time the macro is run.

For example, my formula can be: 
`=SUMIF($A$1:$A$10,$A15,!$C$1:$C$10)`

- I would like to be able to run a macro that would adjust the above
  formula so that instead of adding from `Column C1:C10`, it would add
  `Column D1:10`.
- Then the next time I run the macro, the formula will change again to Column E and so-on.

This formula would then be dragged down to all necessary rows below with the only thing changing is the 2nd part's row #.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the VB code that I got from recording a macro that changes the 3rd part, but as of now it will only change it to that specific column whenever I run it.

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF('WorksheetA'!R5C1:R159C1,RC1,'WorksheetA'!RC13:R159C13)"`

Comment: Changing the formula is simple. The trick is the increment part. Does anything in your sprteadsheet layout provide the column extension automatically - else this value will need to be stored in the file somewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code stores the number of times it has been run in a public variable `LngCNt`. Note that the count will be set to 0 each time the file opens

The `LngCnt` variable is used to increment the formula ie

> first run =SUMIF($A$1:$A$10,$A15,$C$1:$C$10)
>    second run =SUMIF($A$1:$A$10,$A15,$D$1:$D$10)
>    third run =SUMIF($A$1:$A$10,$A15,$E$1:$E$10)

```
Public LngCnt As Long
Sub Macro2()
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(R1C1:R10C1,R[4]C1,R1C" & 3 + LngCnt & ":R10C" & 3 + LngCnt & ")"
  LngCnt = LngCnt + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give this a try now and see if I can get it to work.