# Need assistance with Macro - Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a =SUMIF formula that needs to be adjusted each time the macro is run.  The 3rd part of the formula, the sum range, needs to shift over 1 column each time.  I will be running this once a month (each column represents 1 month)

I got some advice to use a the `LngCnt` variable which worked well.  But now I was forced to add 3 more sections to the same worksheet that all use the =SUMIF formula, all need to be adjusted each time the macro is run, but have different sum ranges (so they are pulling from different columns)

I tried to run the same `LngCnt` variable but quickly ran into the issue where the count is saved so the 2nd section's count started at 2 before the calculation.  I could adjust the starting point so that +2 gets me the appropriate column, but the problem is that I need to do this every month.  Since the count gets reset every time I close the workbook, it would not run properly when I go and run it in the 2nd month.

Here is the link of my original post:
[Excel-Macro Help: LngCnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057384/need-assistance-with-excel-macro-vba)

Here is a part of the code (for 2 of the 4 sections)

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF('Worksheet1'!R5C1:R159C1,RC1,'Worksheet1'!R5C" & 13 + LngCnt & ":R159C" & 13 + LngCnt & ")"
LngCnt = LngCnt + 1
Range("B13").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B13:B17"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("B13:B17").Select
Range("B23").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIF('Worksheet2'!R3C6:R47C6,RC1,'Worksheet2'!R3C" & 16 + LngCnt & ":R47C" & 16 + LngCnt & ")"
LngCnt = LngCnt + 2
Range("B23").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B23:B32"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("B23:B32").Select
```

**Update**

```
> Public LngCnt As Long
Sub Actual()
'
' Actual Macro
'
LngCount = ActiveWorkbook.Names("state").Value

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF('Workbook1'!R5C1:R159C1,RC1,'Workbook1'!R5C" & 13 + LngCnt & ":R159C" & 13 + LngCnt & ")"
    LngCnt = LngCnt + 1
    Range("B13").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B13:B17"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B13:B17").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Names("state").Value = LngCnt
End Sub
```

Comment: You could make this a public variable and set its value on the Workbook_Open event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way of keeping this variable in your workbook, without having to assign it directly in to a cell, is to use a named variable.  From the Formula ribbon, open the names manager, and add a new name called "state". You can give it any value at this point.  We will modify your VBA to update it.

[image: Names Manager]

Then, in your code, you can assign a value to this "variable" by doing:

`ActiveWorkbook.Names("state").Value = LngCnt`

You can retrieve the value by:

`LngCount = ActiveWorkbook.Names("state").Value`

**Update**

```
Public LngCnt As Long
Sub Actual()
'
' Actual Macro
Dim startRange as Range: Set startRange = Range("B13")
    LngCnt = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Names("state").Value, "=", "")
    startRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF('Workbook1'!R5C1:R159C1,RC1,'Workbook1'!R5C" & 13 + LngCnt & ":R159C" & 13 + LngCnt & ")"
    LngCnt = LngCnt + 1
    startRange.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B13:B17"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    'Range("B13:B17").Select  '## I comment this line because I don't think its necessary.
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("state").Value = LngCnt

End Sub
```

After running the macro twice, the saved value of Name("state") is `2`. I save & close the workbook, re-open it, and confirm it is still `2`:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Where is the *first* place in your code where you assign a value to `LngCnt` variable?  Change that line to `LngCount = ActiveWorkbook.Names("state").Value`. All subsequent references to `LngCount` will simply use the value previously "saved" in the Name.

Comment: I initially have `Public LngCnt As Long` declared and then the next time I use `LngCnt` is in the code as shown above in the original post. So I guess the first place where I assign it as value is `LngCnt = LngCnt + 1`.  So I change that line with `LngCount = ActiveWorkbook.Names("state").Value`? And by doing this my count gets saved even if I close the workbook?

Comment: You will also have to do `activeworkbook.names ("state").value = LngCnt` before the `exit sub` in order to save the value in the workbook.

Comment: Hm, I tried applying as you have worked out above. I created a name called 'state' and applied the 2 lines of code, one to retrieve and one to store the value. When I run the macro, I see the count stored when I go to the 'Name Manager'. Even when I close the workbook and re-open it the count is still stored in 'Name Manager'. But as soon as I run the macro again, after re-opening workbook, it resets back to 1. (again, thanks for all your help so far)

Comment: I also updated the code above to show you what I have done. I just applied it to one section for now, just to make it easier

Comment: I think you have a typo, you do `LngCount = ...` instead of `LngCnt =`.  I also notice something that I need to change when retreiving the value (it should be `LngCnt = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Names("state").Value, "=", "")`), I have updated my answer with your Actual macro code.

Comment: ah yes you are right, awesome! Thanks for all your help. I will expand this code so that it applies to all 4 sections now. Hopefully won't run into anymore problems. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Do consider marking this answer as "Accepted" so that others with similar problems can see that this is a viable solution.  Cheers!

Comment: Just ran into a problem that hopefully shouldn't be too difficult to resolve. As of right now, the way the code is setup, the macro begins to run at whatever the current highlighted cell is (the active cell) and the SUMIF= formula is applied to that cell.  Then cells B13:B17 are just highlighted and their formulas remain the same.  The only way the macro will run properly, as of now, is if B13 is highlighted before executing it. Do you know how I can resolve this?

Comment: `Range("B13").Select` as the first line of your code will ensure that this is the active cell. However, you are discovering a problem related to programming to the `Active...` or `Selection`, and this is why most people (including myself) will ordinarily recommend never using either `Active` or `Select` methods in your code: You have to constantly keep track of what is active and make sure that your code doesn't conflict with this.  I will update my answer to avoid using the `Active` or `Select` methods, so you see what I mean.

Comment: Gotcha, going forward I will be sure to set a `startRange` rather than use `Active` and `Selection` - thanks again for everything, including your prompt responses!

Answer (score 1):

to keep a "state" one of the best ways is to have a cell in which the state is stored and then

`sheets("state").range("a1").Value`

to get the value and

`sheets("state").range("a1").Value = 1`

to set the value to one.

You dont need a new sheet if you have a space in the original sheet, Just update it accordingly